# GitHub basic login authentication

Tags: github, github-api

I need help with basic authentication in Github.My problem is when i want to access in "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize/" to get a code for obtain the access_token, if i not logged with an account in the computer i'm redirect to login page of github portal.

I want to know if it's possible to login in github previuosly and don't do this redirection.

Thxx o all!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging in first and then hitting the link for authorization? Yes, it should work.